# CefSharp Drag Form C#

Tags: c#, form

Доброго времени суток.

У меня возникла проблема, я хочу перетаскивать форму не за бордер или как у меня сделано - черную полоску сверху, а просто за серый блок на странице.

Но как я не пытался это реализовать, у меня это не получилось.

Подскажите пожалуйста - как это можно реализовать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: WinForms в данный момент, могу и WPF мне лично без разницы. :)

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ сделать это без использования WinApi, примерно такой (перетаскиваем за Label):

```
    int? x, y;

    private void label1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                x = e.X;
                y = e.Y;
            }
            else
            {
                Left += e.X - (int)x;
                Top += e.Y - (int)y;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            x = null;
            y = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: За лейбл можно сделать куда проще, но мне надо не за лейбл, а за серый блок на страницы (А страница сделана на HTML) - Это CefSharp - Ты видимо не так понял вопрос. )

Comment: Не работал с этим фреймворком, поэтому не признал, события формы там ловятся?

Comment: Нет, есть какой то IDragHandler - Но он  работает через задницу, точнее вообще не работает.
P.S Там панель и на эту панель происходит рендер страницы.

Comment: @user199587 положите поверх панели прозрачный элемент и обрабатывайте клик по нему